# Access all ResponseHeaders from XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm making an Ajax call that returns the following response headers

```
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Content-Length: 0
Content-MD5: jUbDCKMfdRQWA1XyjznyeQ==
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 Jul 2020 17:27:54 GMT
ETag: "0x8D821D1EAA19F17"
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-request-id: acfbc2cf-601e-0005-42ba-53545d000000
x-ms-version: 2019-10-10
x-ms-content-crc64: mLX2abWlGfU=
x-ms-request-server-encrypted: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2020 17:27:53 GMT
```

We want to access the value of the Content-MD5, but `xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()`
only returns

```
content-length: 0
last-modified: Mon, 06 Jul 2020 17:27:54 GMT
```

Is there any way to get the other response headers or the actual raw header?

Comment: Not all headers get exposed to the client JavaScript by default: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: That's a solution! You expose the header in the CORS settings and it works.